# In Revelation 12:3 and 13:1, what is the symbolic significance of the different locations of the crowns?

Tags: revelation, symbolism

> Revelation 12:3 (kjv) "And there appeared another wonder in heaven;
> and behold a great red dragon, having seven heads and ten horns, and
> **seven crowns upon his heads**".
>
> Revelation 13:1 (kjv) "  And I stood upon the sand of the sea, and saw
> a beast rise up out of the sea, having seven heads and ten horns, and
> **upon his horns ten crowns**, and upon his heads the name of blasphemy."

What do the crowns signify? What's the reason for the different locations of the crowns? Chapter 17 interprets the 7 heads and 10 horns for us, but does that interpretation apply to both the dragon and beast? Why do they look the same?

Comment: @All I asked and answered this question some time ago......https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/6312/2479

Comment: @All Quick Answer-the "Dragon" appears at 2 Different Times: 1st time is the time of Christ's birth, death, resurrection, 2nd time is at the appearance of the Beast/Antichrist. In Irenaeus's "Against Heresies", he cautioned against making conclusions until "in the first place, the division of the kingdom into ten; then, in the next place, when these kings are reigning, and beginning to set their affairs in order, and advance their kingdom".(Book V, Chapter 30, vs 2)

Comment: @Tau I love Irenaeus' work "against heresies", I've read his views on revelation,  Daniel, and 2 Thessalonians.  I agree with alot of it but disagree with some of it.  The division of the kingdom that he spoke of happened a long time ago, at the fall of the roman empire by the goth tribes.  Western rome became a divided kingdom where that papacy was able to rise to power. But your comment doesn't answer my questions,  your basically saying that you don't know.

Comment: I did answer it; both in the answer to a question I asked which was highlighted, and the simple answer I just gave. Since I am basically saying it's a "Duplicate Answer", I won't re-write what I have previously written. The "symbolism" of the crowns is who is in power: the crowns on the "Heads" indicates it's the Time of the 'Head' nations, one of which was Rome, which was in power during the time of John. Irenaeus bears this out. The crowns on the "Horns" indicates the 10 Nations/Colonies that sprang out of Rome. They are in power during the Antichrist time.

Comment: (cont.) These nations(Britain, France, Germany, Spain, Holland, etc) that were colonies, and NOT kingdoms/nations in their own right during the Time of Rome, in the Future become nations in their own right and lend their authority to the Antichrist. The crowns NOW are on the Horns-not the Heads...the 'Heads' time has passed.

Comment: I disagree with your view on the nation's when the Roman Empire was divided.  But your just trying to support your futurist view so I understand. The early church fathers were more of historcists than futurists. The time of the 10 horns already happened in the 5th century,  the little horn was the papacy rising to power over the divided Empire,  the horns gave their power and obedience to the papacy. The papacy exalted itself in the temple/church.  Prophecy was fulfilled perfectly and Christ can literally return any moment,

Comment: It will be at a time when no one is expecting it, everyone just going about their lives without a care. Like the days of noah

Comment: But I agree with what you said about the crowns,  I knew that much. Was just hoping to see more detailed answers

Comment: (con.t-finally) PS-The Dragon and Beast are one in the Same(Rev. 12:3/Rev. 13:1). They look the same, have the same features, same feet, same number of Heads and Horns. The only Difference is where the crowns are located-and that is because the same Dragon appears at 2 Different Times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67658/discussion-between-tau-and-diego-b).

Comment: I have answered a similar question here-https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/6312/why-are-the-crowns-on-the-heads-of-the-beast-with-7-heads-and-10-horns-in-re/6346?noredirect=1#comment59467_6346

Answer (score 1):

The Drakon is the Entity also named Serpent, Satan, Lucifer, Diabolos, Beelzebul,  Poneros, Kategoros, Antidikos and, I would say, Anomos. 
Ten descriptions, but none a personal name. Gabriel and Michael have
personal names, but not this one.

As Drakon, his regal rule is exerted by a diverse intelligence - both instantaneous and in several locations, but connected (without anyone
being aware of it) to one Source. An apparent diversity, but not so.
Very modern, this. But the diversity is a lie. There is one, common
denominator and he is - utterly - wicked.

The result of this is a Beast rising out of the seas of the nations.
Disparate individuals are moved as one body, due to an internal and
shared influence (of which they will be unaware).

The rule of the Drakon, exerted by intelligence, becomes (on earth)
a movement of common force - so the rule is, apparently, through
the horn, the symbol of exerted energy focused upon a point.

And we are in the midst of this, this very day.

Comment: So your saying the beast came out from being under the influence of the dragon? But this didn't answer the difference between the the crowns on the head or horns.  And also ch 17 tells us the horns represent 10 kings,  it's not good to put our own interpretations  to it.

Comment: No, I do not believe the Beast comes out of that influence. And, yes, the power of the sea of humanity is exerted through a diversity of kingly force.But, seen spiritually, the force on earth becomes focused in a different way, still under the influence of the Entity described as Drakon. Nigel.

Comment: Sorry your answers are hard to understand and they don't address my oringal questions.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple.

The beast in Revelation 12 represents Satan via Pagan Rome.
The beast in Revelation 13 represents Satan via Papal (Catholic) Rome

Revelation 17 reveals Revelation 12 and 17.

The 7 heads in Revelation 12 with crowns = the 7 kings which are the 7 powers that enslaved Gods people
The 7 heads in Revelation 13 with NO crowns = the 7 hills of Rome or the Papacy in general.

Comment: Are you able to show *from the text* how these things are so?

Answer (score 0):

One difference between the dragon and the sea beast is that the dragon has diadems (crowns) on its heads (Rev 12:3) while the sea beast has diadems on its horns. This may be understood as follows:

> Firstly, Revelation 13:1-2 is solidly based on Daniel 7 and must be
> interpreted on the basis of that chapter. See [here](https://revelationbyjesuschrist.com/the-beast/#links) for a
> discussion.
>
> In Daniel 7, there first are four beasts with seven heads in total.
> **After the last beast follows ten horns**.
>
> Therefore, the crowns on the heads of the dragon imply that it exists
> in the time of the heads in Daniel 7. In other words, the dragon is
> one of the four beasts of Daniel 7. [Another article](https://revelationbyjesuschrist.com/the-beast/) identifies the dragon as the Roman Empire.
>
> The crowns on the horns of the sea beast mean that it exists in the
> time of the horns of Daniel 7. This further means that the sea beast
> is one of the horns of Daniel’s fourth beast! In other words, the sea
> beast is a fragment or remnant of the Roman Empire.